# missing module sqlite3 on python 3.5

Tags: python, sqlite, centos, python-import, python-3.5

I'm told that SQLite3 is on the standard library with python 3.5.  I am on CENTOS7.  When trying my first django app on centos7, I receive the notorious `No module named '_sqlite3'` error.  when I tried to import sqlite3 via pip3.5, the response is `No matching distribution found for sqlite3`.

What am I missing?  I did a `yum install SQLite` and `python-devel` and that worked, but I still receive the error.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try yum install sqlite-devel? You may also have to specify the version. I.e. yum install python3-devel.

Comment: SQLite-devel is installed, and python35-devel does not exist.  Where do I go?  Thanks

Comment: I found the python34-devel packages in the EPEL repo here: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repoview/letter_p.group.html But, there's no mention of a python35 package. You could try to use these extra packages (https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL shows you how to activate them), but there's no guarantee it will work.

Comment: Not sure about centos, but I recently fell in same trap in FreeBSD. Unix-like packagers do a nice job by keeping all dependencies, but often only create minimal packages that do not contain a full Python installation. You should look in the list of packages for your release of centos is there is one related to both Python and SQLite3

Comment: BTW: the error when installing sqlite3 from pip is normal: sqlite3 module is included in the standard Python installation and should never be pulled with pip. The problem is that package maintainers removed it (and I hope hided it in another package).